# python aiogram отправка сообщений при возникновения события

Tags: python, aiogram

Можно ли в aiogram сделать так:
при возникновении события он отправлял сообщение в канал, т.е. без обращения напрямую.
пример:
произошло отключение электричества, бот написал в канал "отключение электричества".
Если да то как?
спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Создаете функцию в отдельном потоке которая в бесконечном цикле проверяет произошло событие или нет, если произошло то вызывает функцию отправки сообщения в канал.

Comment: async def func():
    while True:
        if power_battery_or_no() == 'Электричество кончилось ':
            await bot.send_message(channel_id, f'{power_battery_or_no()}')  вот так не работает.